# How do I display the details of two columns when they are both FK's, referencing the same PK

Tags: sql, oracle

I'll try and word my issue as clearly as I can. I am creating a database in Oralce SQL Developer for school and we have to be able to query specific data once our databases have been created. So here is my issue;

I have an Avatar table that lists the information of all Avatars created in the game, Avatars can evolve into Super Avatars and two Super Avatars can breed to create a Mega Avatar. All these different types of Avatar have their attributes stored in the Avatar table. One of the queries requires me to retrieve the details of all parent Avatars and their Mega Avatar children.

To do this, I created a link table between SuperAvatar and MegaAvatar that simply has FatherID (FK) and MotherID (FK) both linking to the same table; SuperAvatar.SuperAvID (PK). The last column in the link table is MegaAvID (FK) which links to the MegaAvatar.MegaAvID (PK) table.

I will include a picture of my ERD and a screenshot of me running the query.

When I write the following query, I receive no results. Why is this, can anyone see where i'm going wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT AvatarName AS "Fathers", AvatarName AS "Mothers"

FROM MegaAvatar, MegaAvParents, SuperAvatar, Avatar

WHERE MegaAvatar.MegaAvID=MegaAvParents.MegaAvID 
AND MegaAvParents.FatherID=SuperAvatar.SuperAvID 
AND MegaAvParents.MotherID=SuperAvatar.SuperAvID 
AND SuperAvatar.SuperAvID=Avatar.AvatarID;
```

[image: ERD]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Hopefully, you are not learning archaic, out-of-date syntax in your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines are problematic:

```
AND MegaAvParents.FatherID=SuperAvatar.SuperAvID 
AND MegaAvParents.MotherID=SuperAvatar.SuperAvID
```

They mean, you are querying only for MegaAvParents that have the same father and mother. I guess in your dataset there are only MegaAvParents for which FatherID != MotherID.
To fix this, you need to join with SuperAvatar and Avatar twice and give appropriate aliases. For example:

```
SELECT father.AvatarName AS "Fathers", mother.AvatarName AS "Mothers"

FROM MegaAvatar, MegaAvParents, SuperAvatar sFather, SuperAvatar sMother, Avatar father, Avatar mother

WHERE MegaAvatar.MegaAvID = MegaAvParents.MegaAvID
AND MegaAvParents.FatherID = sFather.SuperAvID
AND MegaAvParents.MotherID = sMother.SuperAvID
AND sFather.AvatarID = father.AvatarID
AND sMother.AvatarID = mother.AvatarID;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am now using your example to pull more information from my query! :D